# CoordinatorLayout with RecyclerView Scroll bug

Tags: android, android-layout

Here's what I want

[image]

Please help me with my problem.

1. I have this view but scroll on first `RecyclerView` doesn't work correctly. Plus I want to add that I show first `RecyclerView` click on `TextView`. What do I do wrong? Or help me to build a layout.
2. Maybe somebody knows why when we add items to `RecyclerView` and RecyclerView has height  = 0. Items show only on click on empty space

Here's the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="com.bottlemessage.btlmsg.view.module.game.wallet.WalletActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wallet_activity_back_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/selector_background_back_btn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.bottlemessage.btlmsg.view.util.view.TextTypeface
        android:id="@+id/wallet_activity_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:text="@string/wallet_activity_title"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/wallet_activity_back_btn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/wallet_activity_back_btn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/wallet_activity_back_btn"
        app:typeface="textbook_bold"
        tools:text="Discounts" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/wallet_activity_separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#E9EBF0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wallet_activity_title" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/wallet_activity_main_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wallet_activity_separator">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/appbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:elevation="0dp">

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        layout="@layout/wallet_activity_toolbar" />

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/wallet_activity_separator2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                        android:background="#E9EBF0"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wallet_activity_title" />

                </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

                <com.chauthai.overscroll.RecyclerViewBouncy
                    android:id="@+id/wallet_activity_recycler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/wallet_activity_item_copy_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_rectangle_item_expand_in_wallet"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/wallet_activity_item_empty_list_block"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"

                        android:src="@drawable/ic_empty_discount_list" />

                    <com.bottlemessage.btlmsg.view.util.view.TextTypeface
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:text="@string/discount_activity_no_discounts_yet"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/wallet_activity_whoops_block"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```